# Serial communication not working. Readfile goes wrong

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port, readfile, fpga

After hours of browsing and reading, I still can't figure out why my code isn't working. I saw similar code snippets on different websites, but I can't seem to get it to work. The writing part is working, but the reading goes wrong. Every 'real character' is followed by three null terminators. Writing a string of 19 characters works and the FPGA I am using gives the correct data on the display. The FPGA should reverse the input and send this pack to the serial port. In the Hyperterminal this is working without any problem.

Can someone maybe point me on my mistake and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance =)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include    <commdlg.h>
//#include  <windef.h>
#define    BUFFERLENGTH 19

void writeToSerial(char *line, HANDLE hSerial, DWORD dwBytesWritten);
void printBuffer(char * buffRead, DWORD dwBytesRead);


int main(){
    HANDLE hSerial;
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
    COMMCONFIG dcbSerialParams;
    char *line, *buffWrite, *buffRead;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten, dwBytesRead;
    /* Create a handle to the serial port */    
    hSerial = CreateFile("COM3",
                            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                            0,
                            NULL,
                            OPEN_EXISTING,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                            NULL);
    /* Check if the handle is valid */                        
    if(hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
       if(GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND){
          printf("Serial port does not exist \n");
       }else{
          printf("Port occupied. Please close terminals!\n");
       }
    }else{
       printf("Handle created\n");    
       /* Check the state of the comm port */
       if(!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams.dcb)){
          printf("Error getting state \n");
       }else{
          printf("Port available\n"); 
          /* Configure the settings of the port */
          dcbSerialParams.dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams.dcb);
          /* Basic settings */    
          dcbSerialParams.dcb.BaudRate = CBR_57600;
          dcbSerialParams.dcb.ByteSize = 8;
          dcbSerialParams.dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
          dcbSerialParams.dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
          /* Misc settings */
          dcbSerialParams.dcb.fBinary = TRUE;
          dcbSerialParams.dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;
          dcbSerialParams.dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
          dcbSerialParams.dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
          dcbSerialParams.dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
          dcbSerialParams.dcb.fDsrSensitivity= FALSE;
          dcbSerialParams.dcb.fAbortOnError = TRUE;
          /* Apply the settings */
          if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams.dcb)){
            printf("Error setting serial port state \n");
          }else{
            printf("Settings applied\n");  
            GetCommTimeouts(hSerial,&timeouts);
              //COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = {0};
            timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
            timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
            timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
            timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
            timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier= 10;

            if(!SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts)){
                  printf("Error setting port state \n");
            }else{
                /* Ready for communication */
                line = "Something else\r";
                //****************Write Operation*********************//
                writeToSerial(line, hSerial, dwBytesWritten);
                //***************Read Operation******************//
                if(ReadFile(hSerial, buffRead, BUFFERLENGTH, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
                   printBuffer(buffRead, dwBytesRead);                     
                }
             }          
          }
       }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
void printBuffer(char * buffRead, DWORD dwBytesRead){
     int j;
     for(j = 0; j < dwBytesRead; j++){
         if(buffRead[j] != '\0'){    
           printf("%d: %c\n", j, buffRead[j]);
         }
     }   
}

void writeToSerial(char *line, HANDLE hSerial, DWORD dwBytesWritten){
    WriteFile(hSerial, line, 19, &dwBytesWritten,NULL);
    if(dwBytesWritten){
       printf("Writing success, you wrote '%s'\n", line);
    }else{
       printf("Writing went wrong =[\n");      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
if(ReadFile(hSerial, buffRead, BUFFERLENGTH, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
```

the `buffRead` parameter is an uninitialised pointer. Change the declaration to:

```
char *line, *buffWrite, buffRead [BUFFERLENGTH+1];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I allocate the memory now beforehand.
`char line[BUFFERLENGTH];
char buffWrite[BUFFERLENGTH];
char buffRead[BUFFERLENGTH+1];
`
but this doesn't change anything. The problem is I only allocate BUFFERLENGTH+1 for the output of the serial. Since it contains the '\0\0\0' after each 'real' char, the input of length 19 doesn't fit in the buffer of length 19+1. I thought it would require (BUFFERLENGTH*4)-4 char, but this is too big. I want to correct the null chars afterwards by cleaning the 'dirty buffer' into a new string by neglecting the '\0', but that seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper terminal probably doesn't display null characters so it's possible that your fpga is actually sending them.

You could try testing it with Br@y Terminal in hex mode, or looking at the line with an oscilloscope.

Comment: In Br@y Terminal I see indeed the 3 null characters, which don't show up in the HyperTerminal. I can't look at it which the oscilloscope, since I am using an USB cable. 

I guess my echo program on the FPGA isn't working properly then, so I should fix that before I can make it work in C..